# BWA tool with hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, burrows-wheeler-transform

Burrows-Wheeler Aligner(BWA), a bioinformatic tool (algorithm) to map short nucleotide sequences to a reference genome. I have tried to run BWA using Hadoop Streaming but getting error.

Command:

```
hadoop/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.1.1.jar -input /user/hduser/bwainput/chr21.fa -output /user/hduser/bwa_output17 -mapper "/home/hduser/Desktop/bwa-0.7.5a/bwa index /user/hduser/bwainput/chr21.fa" -file /home/hduser/Desktop/bwa_input/chr21.fa
```

Error Message:

```
INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: /ubuntu:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201401230236_0007
ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful.
Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount:1
INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
```

Please suggest how to resolve this issue? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can run bwa mem tool with hadoop streaming with the help of following command

```
hduser@ubuntu:~/apps/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.1.1.jar -input /user/hduser/fastq/ERR091571.fastq -output 

/user/hduser/bwa_output33 -mapper 'bwa mem -p s_suis.fa -' -reducer 'cat' -file bwa -file s_suis.fa -file s_suis.fa.amb -file s_suis.fa.ann -file s_suis.fa.bwt -file s_suis.fa.pac -file s_suis.fa.sa -numReduceTasks 1
```

Refer this [link](http://www.bumc.bu.edu/gsi/files/2013/12/Farrell_slides.pdf) for more details